# TextToSpeech onUtteranceCompleted bug

Tags: android

When I use an Android `TextToSpeech`
and use `OnUtteranceCompletedListener()`
I'm having memory issues.
If you do not use `OnUtteranceCompletedListener()`
then everything is fine.

Why?

```
final Runnable finish = new Runnable() 
{
   public void run() 
   {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(main.this, main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
   }
};


public void SAY_TTS()
{     
    final HashMap<String, String> ttsParams = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    ttsParams.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "done"); 
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {
        public void onInit(int status) 
        {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)   
            { 
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
                    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttID) 
                    {
                        tts.stop();
                        tts.shutdown();
                        handler_finish.post(finish);
                    }   
                });

                tts.speak("this is a test", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, ttsParams);                 

            }
        }
    });       
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "beginning to disappear memory"? How did you observe that? What tools do you use to track that?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else sees this problem, I think the problem is actually in the case when you're **not** using the `OnUtteranceCompletedListener`. If you don't use it, you're never calling `tts.shutdown()`, which means the `TextToSpeech` resources are never released, which causes Android to complain when your `Activity` ends (because it sees that you haven't cleaned up after yourself).